# Can get-childitem be filtered by file type and date (created in last 7 days by sytem date) at the same time? If not, how can i combine them?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I currently have a script I use to show me .dat files in certain folders. Now, I would like it to return .dat files only created in the last 7 days (from date of execution in task scheduler). I found $time=(Get-Date).AddDays(-7) in one of the questions on here and think this is my solution but not sure how to combine it with what i have currently. This is my script below.

```
$searchDir = "z:\G29"

$searchFile = "*.dat"

$outputDir = "d:\AuditLog\AuditLog_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).txt"

$time=(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchDir -Recurse -Filter $searchFile    -EA SilentlyContinue | 
 Select                CreationTime,                   Fullname |
  format-table  -wrap -autosize  |
 
 Out-File $outputDir -Append
```

I have added the solution I found but I seem to be missing a part. I realize now $time=(Get-Date).AddDays(-7) is just a declaration but how do i call it in the next line
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchDir -Recurse -Filter $searchFile    -EA SilentlyContinue |

Comment: `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchDir -Recurse -Filter $searchFile    -EA SilentlyContinue |  where{$_.LastWriteTime -ge (GetDate).AddDays(-7)} | select ...`

Comment: It errors and returns nothing. Maybe I am adding it wrong. This is what i have now.

Comment: $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchDir -Recurse -Filter $searchFile    -EA SilentlyContinue | 
 where{$_.LastWriteTime -ge (GetDate).AddDays(-7)}  |
 Select                CreationTime,                   Fullname |

Comment: `get-date` was missing the `-` Try `$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $searchDir -Recurse -Filter $searchFile -EA SilentlyContinue | where{$_.CreationTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | Select CreationTime, Fullname `

Comment: Did not error but now the output file is empty. I must be missing something

Comment: haha. It is empty because nothing is within 7 days. I will test this but I think you have resolved my issue.

Comment: Perfect. I changed to creation time and added a recent file and now is working great! Thanks for everything!

Comment: Thanks again, Master of the Shell! I have banging my head for two days trying to make this work!

Comment: `dir -r . *.dat | ? { (get-date) - $_.LastWriteTime -le '7'}`